# iPhone OpenGL ES save/load

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, caeagllayer

I'm working from the GLPaint example and have no idea how to implement a "save to" and "load from" a file. I don't want the drawing points, but to save the actual buffer so I can load it later, like a photoshop document or any other popular paint app. How is this possible?

Saving to an image doesn't seem like it would work unless its possible to render it into opengl once loaded, but even then it seems some of the quality would be lost from compression and the conversion process.

I thought about saving the drawing points, but loading that seems difficult, because somehow the colors would have to be save too and aligned once loaded.

Note: GLPaint uses caegllayer.

Thanks,
austin

Comment: this looks promising: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1861

Comment: Thanks for the link, it appears they are just saving an image, which I think is my only choice. I guess if I save it as a lossless PNG it should be ok. I will then just have to redraw it as a texture when loaded/opened... I hope drawing an image into OpenGL ES is lossless too.